# My database updates just expire after a system restart and are not saved properly

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Good evening!
Since this morning, without actually changing anything, I have the problem that when I want to change a value in my database via `UPDATE` statement, it is not changed in the database.

The funny thing here is that getting the updated value in the next line then also returns the changed value, but after a restart and several phpmyadmin reloads the value still hasn't changed in the database itself.

So somehow UPDATE statement only affect the current execution of the system and not the actual database. Could this be some problem with the caching of my MySQL methods/libraries?
If you have any further questions, please feel free to contact me!
Thanks in advance! :)

*DatabaseHelper.java*

```java
   public void editEntry(SearchCondition condition, EditValue... editValues) {
        StringBuilder editCommand = new StringBuilder("UPDATE `" + table.getName() + "` SET ");

        for (int i = 0; i < editValues.length; i++) {
            EditValue editValue = editValues[i];
            editCommand.append("`" + editValue.getColumn() + "` = " + editValue.getValue());
            if (i < editValues.length - 1) {
                editCommand.append(", ");
            }
        }
        editCommand.append(" WHERE ")
                .append("`" + condition.getColumn() + "` = '" + condition.getValue() + "'")
                .append(";");
        System.out.println(editCommand);
        Core.getDatabase().update(editCommand.toString());
    }

    public Object getEntry(SearchCondition... conditions) {
        StringBuilder searchCommand = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM `")
                .append(table.getName())
                .append("`");
        if (conditions.length > 0) {
            searchCommand.append(" WHERE ");
            for (int i = 0; i < conditions.length; i++) {
                SearchCondition condition = conditions[i];
                searchCommand.append("`" + condition.getColumn() + "` = \"" + condition.getValue() + "\"");
                if (i < conditions.length - 1) {
                    searchCommand.append(", ");
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = Core.getDatabase().getResult(searchCommand.toString());
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                return resultSet.getObject(name);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

*Main.java*

```java
  DataTable.load("stackoverflow").getColumn("id").editEntry(new SearchCondition("name", "justin"), new EditValue("id", 12));
  System.out.println(DataTable.load("stackoverflow").getColumn("id").getEntry(new SearchCondition("name", "justin"));
```

*Output*

```
[System] Started MyExampleProject...
UPDATE `stackoverflow` SET `id` = 12 WHERE `name` = 'justin';
12
```

*Database Value in phpmyadmin before and after execution of the system*

```
26
```

Disclaimer: Yes, I made sure that the `DataTable.load()` and `getColumn()` function work correctly and no caching function was included on my part, but the `getEntry()` method grabs fresh from the database.

Comment: What does `Core.getDatabase().update(...)` do? How is the DB connection setup?  Is auto commit enabled? Side note - see also: SQL Injection

Comment: probably auto-commit is disabled and code is not executing a commit, so the actual transaction *sees* the updated value, but it is not yet stored in the table

Comment: **WARNING**: Be sure to use [prepared statements with placeholder values](http://bobby-tables.com/java) to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @AndrewS thank you very much for your feedback!

My Database Connector Class looks like this:
https://hastebin.com/arazubupiz.java

And I'm just using the `con.prepareStatement(<query>)` method and `preparedStatementVariable.executeUpdate()` after it.

I also once had the returned integer from executeUpdate output to the console, which also confirmed that a line had been changed. :/

Comment: @user16320675 thanks for the hint!
Where would I check something like that and change if necessary?

Comment: @tadmanyes, I already do, thank you! In the example I have now only directly injected, since I had the assumption that it could be due to PreparedStatements :/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `AUTOCOMMIT` setting was disabled in MySQL, my changes were not applied to the database when performing an update.
But by using `.commit()` after all necessary changes everything works correctly now!
Thanks a lot! :)